# HVAC Preventative Maintenance - Is required or company is selling me for no reason?

Tags: hvac

Given the texas heat, I proactively scheduled regular ac maintenance which was supposed to include cleaning & inspection. But they didn't do cleaning and only did inspection. Upon Inspection, they are asking for following repairs:

1. Capacitor - rated for 45/5 but actual is 42/4.8. they are asking for me to replace it. $240.
2. Ac disconnect switch - they are saying it is broken and AC cannot be turned off from it. you have to kill it from the breaker. how is it a problem? asking $350
3. Hard Start Kit - they are saying that during maintenance it locked up once and suggested to install hard start kit as a fix. they called me again next day and warned me that my compressor will burn out, if the lock up happens again. I am not sure if this will void warranty. asking $375

My unit is from trane and is 3T was installed by previous owners in 2016 and would be still under 10 year warranty.

so far, I have paid them their service/trip fee only. wondering, are these repairs really required?

Comment: There are some real HVAC pros here, so just comments: 1 - absolutely crazy. 2 - that is serious if true - **Test it yourself.** See if the disconnect works - if it does, they're lying. If it doesn't then it is a real concern. But price sounds high. 3 - heard of hard start kits but don't know much about them, but really dubious about this.  I think it is time to look for a new company...

Comment: A disconnect, if faulty, costs like $20 or less (I paid $8 each for 60A disconnects circa 2020) so that's some absurd labor rate for a fall-off-a-log easy replacement. It IS a necessary thing to have working correctly. Stinks of scammers.

Comment: How did you find this company? Were they the company whose name was on the A/C equipment i.e. original provider, or did you just google someone?  Because those search engine results are pretty much locked up by scammers and lead generators (who sell your name to hustlers).   But you can see for yourself whether the A/C disconnect works.

Comment: There's a lot of "Those who can, do; those who can't, pay" in HVAC and electrical work.  Heck, any home maintenance, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, the heating and air conditioning tune-up services are often kind of a scam... They'll send a tech and he'll do some stuff, but mostly it's wiping off the dust, spit-shining a thing or two, maybe change a filter and, as you've found, finding any little thing they can scare you into repairing no matter how frivolous.

Capacitors are often rated to +/- 6 to 10 percent. Yours looks entirely within spec to me. No way I'd replace it. The part only costs about US$20, and they might mark up supplies they keep in the service van 100%, and they might reasonably charge an hour of labor too. Their price is still shockingly high.

Disconnect switch is important. It's required by electrical code. A technician needs to use it when servicing the equipment, and it needs to be within sight of the equipment so that a well-meaning person won't turn it on not knowing that there's a technician with his head, fingers, or whetever else inside the machine. But IMHO they're asking way too much for the repair.

Hard start kit is a real thing. But if you're not hearing the compressor routinely straining to start (a strong hum) or seeing the lights in the house dim, and never experiencing a circuit breaker tripping, it's probably not really needed.

Comment: thanks for the insight Greg! you saved me from getting ripped off